# AngularJS and link redirection with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to use angularJS to **scroll smoothly** directly to the section specified in the link.
For example, starting link:

https://stackoverflow.com/#footer

This will redirect me to the footer of that page instantly. So I want to create an angular controller to manage this situation. My Idea is to create an angular controller something like this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var target = $location.hash();
    .... (function to go smoothly to that point) ....
}
```

The problem is that the hash() function returns an empty string. Where is the problem?

Comment: You can do that directly in you html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, you can use one of this two good library:

- https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSmoothScroll
- https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll